# How do I make JPA merge insert new child objects for a OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm having trouble getting my merge to cascade down when there are new child objects.
I have a parent object (City) with a set of child objects

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
public Set<Street> getStreets() {
    return streets;
}
```

And a child object (Street) referencing the parent

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="City", nullable=false)
public City getParentCity(){
    return parentCity;
}
```

And I'm running a daily routine to dump information into the database. All well and dandy until JPA runs into a new street. When it gives me an EntityNotFoundException. I'm assuming that it means there's no street already in the database with the new ID. From what I've read it's because the child is the actual owner of the transaction, but I need it to persist the new object if it runs into this "EntityNotFound" exception

I'm not using an auto-generated primary key, It's a key that already exists in the dataset. Currently I have access to a micro-service that uses em.merge() on the parent object.

I see that there's an option to delete objects that no longer exist (orphanRemoval); is there a way to add new ones?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you are trying to save or merge the collection and parent. As you have the bidirectional mapping, you need to have bidirectional association, like `parent.getChildren().add(newChild);` and newChild.setParent(parent);`

Comment: Currently I'm just calling em.merge() on the parent object. Is there a way to have the entity manager take care of this automatically? Like how it does with orphans?

Comment: This link might be a little help for you. http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/23/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/

Comment: Sorry for misconception, `merge()` does inserts (if needed). In your case, is `@Id` is autogenerated or assigned? If it is not assigned, then it will assume that the object is there and try to update. http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/307

Comment: @RP - the behavior that I see is that merge() does *not* insert as needed. Instead of inserting, it throws an EntityNotFoundException. The `@Id` is populated from the incoming dataset and is assigned pre-merge. You're saying that if the `@Id` is auto-generated it tries to update? What does it try to update if it doesn't know the Id of the record to update?

Comment: That xebia link seems to indicate that I do need to DIY merge the child objects before sending it to the em. Thanks for that link

Comment: Yes, that is the usual way, but `merge` does almost same, like it first fires a select and then insert or update. About the `@Id`, if it is auto generated, it might check for null or zero to decide on wheather to insert or update, but it is assigned, it will fire a select and decide wheather to update or insert, it is strange that is not the case here, It is behaving differently in `@ManyToOne`. Whenever I have this kind of situations, I usually check if the entity is there and proceed with merge or persist.

Comment: You simply have a wrong mappedBy... Replace `mappedBy = "parent"` with `mappedBy = "parentCity"`

Comment: You're correct Michele it should be parentCity in this example. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is the case, but with me, only works if I put the hibernate's annotations above the variable attributes themselves, not on getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was 'manually' saving first the street, and then the City.